# VSCode Ctrl + S

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on a React project using a Visual Studio Code. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in the Visual Studio Code to save file, it removes all the JavaScript formatting or scatters all the code in the file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `"files.autoSave": "onFocusChange"`  saves changes automatically, this works fine for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You disable it "Format On Save"

1. Press Ctrl + <
2. Search "Format On Save" It's must be disabled.
   [image: It's must be disabled]

Comment: Checking the box on "Format on Save" would solve the issue.

Answer (score 15):

Try disable extensions for auto-formatting javascript code. Sometimes Beautify, JS-CSS-HTML Formatter can mess things up.

Maybe auto-formatting is on in settings as well. Check File > Preferences > Settings and look at the "User settings"-tab. Look if "editor.formatOnSave" is set to 'true',  change that to 'false' in that case.

Hope that helps. If not, please send a list of your activated extensions.

Answer (score 8):

To expand on Tuxedo Joe's answer, your issue might be with your formatter extension:

Check if "Format On Save" is disabled

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>
2. Search "Format On Save". Set to disabled.

Disable formatting on save in `formatter.json`:

1. Press <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Enter "Formatter Config"
3. In `formatter.json` set "onSave" to false
4. Save `formatter.json`
5. Restart VSCode

Answer (score 2):

select language mode by clicking on your bottom right hand from javascript/html to react

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check whether 'Format on Safe' is enabled or not.

- Cntrl + < , (or File > Preferences > Settings)
- Search 'Format on Safe',
- Disable 'Format on Safe'.

If you've got it disabled, check the format text. It's probably that you've got javascript or html format. Change it to 'react' or 'javascript react' format.

- 'Select Language Mode',
- Search 'react',
- Select 'react', 'javascript react' or 'typescript react'.

Answer (score 0):

By default VS Code format on save was enabled, you can disable it by following steps:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>
2. Search for javascript edit `javascript.format.enable` to false.

Comment: this solution does not help

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to enabled Default HTML formatter:

Push ***Ctrl + >***, then ***Extentions > HTML***:

Screenshot:
[image]